# How are d3.map() values reset back to default?

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.map() in an update pattern to map some values.

My code looks like this:

```
selectedNeighborhood.map(function(d) { rateById.set(d.endneighborhood, d.rides); }) ;
```

My issue is, when I make a new selection and new update, instead of replacing the existing map with a new set of values, the map is expanded. I would like my map to reset back to default every time I run my update function. How do I go about this?

One working method (not clean) is to set the map object equal to {}, then redefine the map altogether to the variable name.

Comment: What's `selectedNeighborhood` and how, if it's a `d3.map()` does it have a `map()` method? Maybe `selectedNeighborhood` is a d3 selection? If so, calling `map()` on it happens to not throw an error because d3 selection extend JavaScript's Array, which has a `map()` method, but calling `map()` on a d3 selection is not valid operation within the d3 API. Bottom line, it's unclear what you're asking and how this constitutes usage of `d3.map()`.

Comment: selectedNeighborhood is a d3 array of values which I am using to set RateById's map values. Maybe that's not the best solution (all I want to do is to set up a way to create an anonymous function that cascades down the values, to use in my map). I think you are too focused on my specific code snippet and focus on the general problem, though.

Comment: Ok... now I understand... Didn't get that `rateById` was the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-setting `rateById` to a new, blank map is not entirely unclean, but it could cause bugs if there are some objects/functions out there that retain a reference to the value of `rateById` in a separate variable, in which case the existing reference wouldn't update to point to the newly created map.

You want to clear the map "in place" (i.e. mutate it, so that the var `rateById` continues to points to the same `d3.map`). You can do so by looping over its entries and removing them one by one:

```
rateById.forEach(function(key) { rateById.remove(key); });
```

As a side note: it's not a big deal, but still, using Array `map()` for looping, as in `selectedNeighborhood.map(...)` ends up instantiating and returning a new Array of `undefined`s. If `selectedNeighborhood` was a giant array, this would be wasteful (in terms of memory and CPU). Using `selectedNeighborhood.forEach(...)` instead achieves the same result but without creating the new array, so it's more appropriate.